# RegEx - Capturing according to a pattern that matches EVEYTHING.. BUT the repetition of the beginning of the pattern

Tags: regex, regex-group, regex-negation

I struggle with my regex pattern and I need some help.
I'm trying to scrape some javascript content to capture label and value pairs.

I started with this

```
"label" : "(.*)"[\s\S]*?"value" : "(.*)"
```

to scrape something like this

```
"label" : "Something ?",
blabla
blabla2
"value" : "NO"
blabla
"label" : "Foo ?",
blabla
blabla2
"value" : "Bar"
```

It works, it captures the label in the first group and the value in the second.

```
Something ? / NO
Foo ? / Bar
```

My problem is that, sometimes I have a label but NOT a value. In this case I would like to NOT match this isolated label.

Eg :

```
"label" : "Something ?",
blabla
blabla2
"value" : "NO"
blabla
"label" : "YouMad ?",
blabla
"label" : "Foo ?",
blabla
blabla2
"value" : "Bar"
```

gives

```
Something ? / NO
YouMad ? / Bar
```

I tried Negative Lookahead, some other thing... but i'm stuck

Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks

https://regex101.com/r/gG3XxR/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not cross matching label using `(?!"label")[\s\S])*` and use a negated character class `[^` to prevent some backtracking.

```
"label" : "([^"]*)"(?:(?!"label")[\s\S])*"value" : "([^"]*)"
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4hxyP2/1)

Comment: Great ! I wasn't aware of this notion of backtracking, I'll take a closer look.